# Message reaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get my Discord bot to react to people's messages. For example, if somebody said "welcome", the bot will react to their message, because it has the word welcome, which I would set the keyword too. I understand how to get the bot to reply to messages with a response, but not reactions.

Comment: What library are you using to do bot replies?

Comment: @Nisala Sorry, what do you mean by library?

Comment: How are you interacting with Discord?

Comment: Please show the code you have written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discord.js you can use something like this:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", message => {
   if(message.content === "welcome") {
        message.react("");
   }
}

client.login("YOUR_TOKEN");
```

This in the [Discord.js Docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages) might be helpful as well.